# how do i add a scanner so i can insert the values which are then saved on to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql-insert

**basically I need to add another scanner input which after login in to I can add an id and name etc to my database so I don't have to use the set one in the program. the database gets updated when I just change the set insert values so the connection is fine I just don't know how a user would insert the values without the code which would then update the database after entering.**

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JDBCInsertValues{
        static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; // JDBC driver
        static final String DATABASE = "test"; // the database name
        static final String HOST = "10.1.63.200"; // the database host IP
        // the full URL:
        static final String DATABASE_URL = 
                "jdbc:mysql://" + HOST + "/" + DATABASE;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Inserting values into MySQL database table...");
        Connection con = null;
        try{
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Login: ");
            String login = keyboard.next();
            System.out.print("Password: ");
            String password = keyboard.next();         
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,login,password);
            try{
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                String sql = "INSERT INTO Authors VALUES(67,\"Mark\",\"Cooper\")";
                System.out.println(sql);
                int val = st.executeUpdate(sql);          
                System.out.println(val + " rows inserted.");
            }
            catch (SQLException s){
                System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
                s.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating `String sql` using a combination of your current statement and scanner input. You can also use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and replace `67,\"Mark\",\"Cooper\"` with `?,\"?\",\"?\"`, using PreparedStatement's `setInt()` and `setString()` methods to set the values although this approach is better suited for iterating through a list.

Comment: You're already grabbing input using your `Scanner keyboard`, so grab the three fields you need (ie. id, firstName, lastName) using that and then create an SQL string as a combination of what you already have and the strings you got from the user. Eg.: `String sql = "INSERT INTO Authors VALUES(" + id + ",\"" + firstName + "\",\"" + lastName + "\")";`

Comment: well it runs with no syntax errors but when try and use get errors

Comment: You need to be more specific; what errors? Java runtime errors? SQL exceptions? What does the `System.out.println(sql)` output look like? Try editing your original post to include your updated code so we can see what's wrong.